# Bootstrap css theme not loaded in mobile view

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, mobile

I am creating mobile views for my mvc 4 web application. I have installed JQuery.Mobile.MVC in my project. But the CSS theme "a" is not getting loaded in my mobile views. My _Layout.Mobile.cshml looks like the following...

```
          <!DOCTYPE html> 
 <html> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/Mobile/css", "~/Content/jquerymobile/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery", "~/bundles/jquerymobile")
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; 
        });
    </script>

    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.Mobile.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    @RenderSection("Styles", false)

</head> 
  <body> 

<div class="ui-bar-b">
    <ul>
        RAW Online Mobile
    </ul>
</div>
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b">
    @*@Html.Partial("_ViewSwitcher")*@

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
        @RenderSection("Header", required: false)
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        @RenderSection("featured", false)
        @RenderBody()       
    </div>

</div>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

and my Index.Mobile.cshtml looks like the following...

```
@model IEnumerable<RAWOnlineWebandMobile.Models.Company>

@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.Mobile.cshtml";
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

        @section Header{
    <div data-role="button" data-icon="plus" class="ui-header ui-btn-right">
  @Html.ActionLink("New", "Create")
   </div>    
  }




<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="ui-bar-b">
@*<li data-role="list-divider"></li>*@
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li class="ui-bar-b ui-link">
        <a href="Companies/Details/@item.CompanyID">
            <h3>
                @item.CompanyName
            </h3>
        </a>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: Post the bundles code you have included in `styles.render`

Comment: Thanks. I got it. I was rendering styles incorrectly. My bad.